# Утечка памяти в opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

Откуда в этом коде может возникать утечка памяти? Смотрю за процессом через диспетчер задач, потребляемая память каждую секунду увеличивается на 4кб. Как это исправить?

```
#include "GL/freeglut.h"

int width = 640, height = 480;

void dr()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2i(width, 100);
    glVertex2i(width, 0);
    glVertex2i(width, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, 0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void timer(int=0){

    dr();
    glutTimerFunc(50, timer, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    //glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("TEST");

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height);
    glutDisplayFunc(dr);

    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glutTimerFunc(50, timer, 0);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, все дело в функции timer, которую Вы добавляете через glutTimerFunc(50, timer, 0); в список срабатывающих по таймеру коллбэков.

Дело в том, что эта функция где-то в системе регистрирует таймер с коллбэком. Этот таймер, конечно, срабатывает, вызывая вашу функцию. Но вот когда именно ОС освобождает ресурсы, связанные с таймером, известно только самой ОС (или конкретной реализации glut). Таким образом, чтобы заставить все работать, нужно удалить функцию timer (за ненадобностью) и строчку:

```
glutTimerFunc(50, timer, 0);
```

И добавить строчку

```
void glutIdleFunc(dr);
```

Чтобы заставить программу перерисовываться, когда не поступает никакой пользовательский ввод.

Если Вашей целью было поддерживать определенную частоту кадров, ниже, чем способен выдавать OpenGL даже под vsync, то лучше всего померить время кадра функцией

```
int timeSinceStart = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
```

Она вернет количество миллисекунд с момента вызова glutInit. После чего "доспать" необходимое время, вызвав в функции dr() какую-нибудь функцию задержки времени, вроде usleep или Sleep.

В целом, документация по всем возможностям доступна по [ссылке](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/spec3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Запустите код из main в цикле на 10хххх, и воспользуйтесь winapi или аналогом linux-а, я выявления использованной памяти процессом (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219(v=vs.85).aspx - для winapi).
В случае утечки, оставьте только Init и Clean, проверьте. Если утечки нет - добавляйте по чуть-чуть и смотрите. Увидите.

Answer (score 1):

Я запускал этот код под valgrind'ом. Там есть утечка в несколько байт, но это похоже потому, что я закрывал приложение по Ctrl+C.